# What is the lexical relationship between 'kingdom' and 'phylum'?

Tags: vocabulary, lexical-relations

In biology [humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human) belong to the kingdom of animalia and the phylum chordata.
Every organism that belongs to chordata belongs also to animalia but not the other way around. Animalia is a hypernym of chordata.

However it doesn't feel like kingdom is a hypernym of phylum. Is there a word for the relationship between the concepts?

Comment: Do you want to say "Bigger structural unit" in one long word?

Comment: @J-mster : I'm not sure whether there's a common term for it. If bigger structural unit is commonly used it's okay.

Comment: Do you mean something like a 'subset' and 'superset'?

Comment: @curiousdannii : I don't think the word kingdom is a superset of phylum the way I understand the word "superset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Kingdom" a higher taxonomic level, higher than "phylum". 
You can probably say "superlevel", if you desperately need it in one word, but I would rather say "higher level in the hierarchy/taxonomy/classification".